# Run Apollo mutation on first render with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, apollo, use-effect

I have a form in a MUI dialogue. I want to create an order when the dialogue first opens. I thought useEffect with empty dependency would do that but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't let the mutation resolve before the setState.

```
  const [createOrder] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER);

  const [activeOrder, setActiveOrder] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const newOrder = async () => {
      await createOrder({
        variables: {
          order: {
            type,
            table,
          },
        },
        refetchQueries: [{ query: ORDERS_QUERY }],
      });
    };

    setActiveOrder(newOrder);
  }, []);

  console.log(activeOrder); // gives me Promise{<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

Also, is the only way to get rid of the missing dependency warning with `// eslint-disable-next-line`?  If I wrap my function in a useCallback to prevent render loop and add the dependencies requested, then useCallback gives me an error that the dependencies are unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here `setActiveOrder(newOrder);`

1. `setActiveOrder` can accept function as an argument and call it;
2. `newOrder` is async function. async function always returns promise;

solution:

```js
/*
maybe your don't need activeOrder, check data from result
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#result
*/
const [createOrder, { data }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER, {
  // https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options
  variables: { type, table },
  refetchQueries: [{ query: ORDERS_QUERY }],
});
const [activeOrder, setActiveOrder] = useState({});
    
useEffect(() => {
  createOrder().then((res) => {
    setActiveOrder(res);
  });
    
}, [createOrder]);

useEffect(() => console.log('data:\n', data), [data]);
useEffect(() => console.log('activeOrder:\n', activeOrder), [activeOrder]);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!